# (It's been a halfyear/a halfyear has passed) since

Tags: time

Which is correct? I think both are, but "it's been a halfyear" would be more idiomatic.

Examples:

> It's been a halfyear since Ai went to a new language school.

> A halfyear has passed since Ai went to a new language school.

Comment: I am not aware of "halfyear" even being a word. When I google "halfyear", I get "half-year". Did you mean "half-year"?

Comment: Are you related to [user:166442]   "Yellowed Keeper" You may have accidentally created a second user account.  You can ask a mod to merge them.  Or you can change your name without creating a new account.  It is considered improper to maintain two accounts

Answer (score 1):

Neither is particularly natural.  For periods less than a year it is better to use "months".

> It has been six months...

> Six months have passed ...

Answer (score 0):

Both work, but I find it more natural to instead say "*It's been half a year since...*" / "*Half a year has passed since...*".